# NoSuchMethod on reading file from a GCP Bucket

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to read a file from a Google Cloud Storage bucket by using this code

```
Blob blob = storage.get(BlobId.of(Constants.GCS_BUCKET, srcFilename));
printBlob(blob.reader());
private void printBlob(ReadChannel reader) {
    try {
        WritableByteChannel outChannel = Channels.newChannel(System.out);
        ByteBuffer bytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(64 * 1024);
        while (reader. read(bytes) > 0) {
            bytes.flip();
            outChannel.write(bytes);
            bytes.clear();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {

    }

}
```

When executing `reader.read(bytes)` then the code throws this exception

```
[INFO] GCLOUD: Caused by: 
[INFO] GCLOUD: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.api.services.storage.Storage$Objects$Get.setReturnRawInputStream(Z)Lcom/google/api/client/googleapis/services/AbstractGoogleClientRequest;
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.cloud.storage.spi.v1.HttpStorageRpc.createReadRequest(HttpStorageRpc.java:658)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.cloud.storage.spi.v1.HttpStorageRpc.read(HttpStorageRpc.java:693)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.cloud.storage.BlobReadChannel$1.call(BlobReadChannel.java:127)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.cloud.storage.BlobReadChannel$1.call(BlobReadChannel.java:124)
```

Comment: It ocurrs on downloading the file too -> blob.downloadTo(Paths.get("/tmp/"+srcFilename));

Comment: Are you following any tutorial?

Answer (score 1):

Solved.
It is needed to use the dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-cloud-core-http</artifactId>
        <version>1.91.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

If you uses 1.90.0 it crashes.

Comment: is this solution working?